# Unable to send email attachment stored in database - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email-attachments

I have a form where the user attaches a file. The file is uploaded to a folder then the full_path link is stored in a database. The link is stored in an array format along with other items.
Here is how it is stored in the database.

```
[{"product_id":"20","product_name":"C4(Big A4) Envelopes","quantity":"1000","image":"\"\\\/home\\\/printlin\\\/public_html\\\/uploads\\\/birthday24.jpg\""}]
```

Now when i want to send my email, I decode the data stored in the database and place the file_path in the attach() function.

```
foreach ($data['shopping_cart'] as $cart_data) { 
        $items = json_decode($cart_data['items'],true);
           foreach ($items as $documents){
              $this->email->attach(stripcslashes($documents['image']));
            }
        }
```

The email gets sent, however it does not come with any attachments.
($documents['image']) appears as:

```
"\/home\/printlin\/public_html\/uploads\/birthday28.jpg"
```

And stripcslashes($documents['image']) appears as:

```
"/home/printlin/public_html/uploads/birthday28.jpg"
```

What could be the problem with my link format??

Comment: If you do a `try { $this->email->attach(stripcslashes($documents['image'])); } catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` what do you get? Also, what I like to try is create the email object and do a print_r to see how it's generated.

Comment: I don't believe CI throws exceptions @MihailMinkov

Comment: @MihailMinkov I create an email object of what exactly???

Comment: @lorrainemutheu before using `$this->email->send()` try this `print_r($this->email)`. The attachments should appear somewhere in there. Otherwise perhaps the path is wrong.

Comment: @lorrainemutheu: try to debug in file: /home/printlin/public_html/system/libraries/Email.php and function attach...

Comment: I have finally gotten the solution. I had used `$image = json_encode($this->upload_image())` to store the full path in the database. I simply removed the `json_encode` and it worked. Though I don't know why.